# ToolbarAndroid react native dynamic subtitle bind to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set "ToolbarAndroid"'s subtitle based on state variable with no success,

I set the initial state to null and I am trying to do something like "display subtitle only if it isn't null"

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      subtitle: null
    }
  }

  render() { ...

  <ToolbarAndroid
   ..
        subtitle={() => {
          if (this.state.subtitle !== null) {
           return this.state.subtitle;
          } else {
           return '';
          }
        }}
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to export this Component. If yes, you can set a default prop as the value of the subtitle.
For example,

```
static defaultProps = {
  subtitle: ''
};

static propTypes = {
   subtitle: PropTypes.string
};
```

So, at the prop of subtitle, you just writing likes this,

```
subtitle={this.props.subtitle}
```

When you want to use this component, just pass a value will be ok~

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it with

```
  subtitle={(this.state.subtitle !== null) ? this.state.subtitle : '' }
```